# How to unhash the object returned from get in memcached

Tags: java, windows-xp, memcached, spymemcached

After doing a set , when i try to get a object from memcached, it gives me a hashed value but i want the values inside the object that was **set** with set function call...

Anyone having idea how to solve it??

#### - The Object is instance of a class having two string attributes.

Comment: Are you using any interface like python-memcached, which in turn is compressing the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spymemcached deserializes and decompresses java objects when you get them back from memcached. If you get an Object back then you should be able to type cast it to the corresponding java object.